# How to send a HTTP POST REQUEST by parameters using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to send a POST request by param similar to that:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9000/api?command={"command":"value","params":{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value","key":value,}}
```

I tried to do that, but not working:

```
    let command: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

    command = command.append('command', 'value');

    params = params.append('key', value);
    params = params.append('key', value);
    params = params.append('key', value);
    params = params.append('key', value);
    command = command.append('params', params.toString());


    this.httpClient.post('/api?', null, {
        params: command
    });


The error is: 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: The error is happening on the server; the problem is not with your JavaScript code. You'll have to look there for the actual problem. (It *might* have to do with the particular parameters you're sending, of course, but you can only find the details by seeing what went wrong in server logs.)\

Answer (score 1):

The code **500** given by the server has the following description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error
>   server error response code indicates that the server encountered an
>   unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

I think your server is trying to process your request.
So remove ".toString()" in your code.

```
command = command.append('params', params.toString());
```

Then  try (Ctrl + shift + Supr) to see chrome dev tools, and go to the Networks tab.
You will see all your calls. Check if your request has the format as you want.

Comment: I found a solution. I don't know if it's a better solution, but it's working. I put my answer in this question. however, thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1) First I create the object containing the command info and parameters. Similar to that:

```
const object = {
  command: 'command description',
  params: {
    properti: value,
    properti: value,
    properti: value,
  }
};
```

2) After, I convert this object to json using JSON.stringify():

```
// convert object to json data
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(object);
```

3) After second step, I encapsulate the json data in HttpParams

```
// encapsulate json data in http param
let httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
httpParams = httpParams.append('command', automationTestTriggerJson);
```

4) and finally, I send POST by param using httpClient. Similar to that:

```
this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, {
        httpParams: parameters
});
```

NOTE: I don't know if it's is a better solution bur it's working for me.